# Alcatel One Touch S'Pop remap power button

Tags: root-access, keyboard, buttons

How can I remap the camera button to work as a power button?
I have a rooted Alcatel One Touch S'Pop.
I edited system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl by copy-pasting POWER WAKE string from the power button to the camera button, turned off the phone and reinserted the battery. Nothing happened. The camera button still activates camera. Now I restored the old file.
In system/usr/keylayout folder, I have these files:

- ACCDET.kl
- AVRCP.kl
- Generic.kl
- hid-keyboard.kl
- mhl-keyboard.kl
- mtk-kpd.kl
- qwerty.kl
- Vendor_05ac_Product_0239.kl
- Vendor_22b8_Product_093d.kl
- Vendor_045e_Product_028e.kl
- Vendor_046d_Product_c216.kl
- Vendor_046d_Product_c294.kl
- Vendor_046d_Product_c299.kl
- Vendor_046d_Product_c532.kl
- Vendor_054c_Product_0268.kl

Which one should I edit?
Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the file `mtk-kpd.kl` and change these values. First, make a backup of that file.

```
key 116 GRAVE
key 212 POWER      WAKE
Key 211 POWER      WAKE
```

Comment: What if the keys are wrong? How will I fix that?